# How to check from other page which tab on tabbar is active

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to create a money manager app and I use tabbar for navigating (just editing tabbed app template)
App has 4 tabs: Expense, Income, Statistics and History.

Expense and Income have the same DataTemplate because income and expense operations are almost the same

I created class BudgetOperation to represent my income and expenses

```
public class BudgetOperation
{
    private long id;
    private float amount;
    private DateTime date;
    private string description;
    private OperationCategory operationCategory; //I mean source of money (salary, pocket monet etc)
                                                // or on what we spent money (food, transport etc)
    private OperationType operationType;//Income or Expense

}
```

User should enter some info about his operation on my OperationPage so I can collect amount of money and comment from page, assign date when operation will be created and the main problem for me is to determine is it income or expense.
For solving this problem I want to check if expense tab is opened its expense operation if income its income

Please give me advice how can I determine active tab of TabBar or some other way to identify type of my operation

Here my OperationPage.xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Money_Manager.Views.OperationPage"
             x:Name="currentPage">             
            
             

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter  Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
                <Setter  Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource Expence}"/>-->
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Grid.ColumnSpan ="6" Grid.RowSpan="8" BorderColor="Black" CornerRadius="0"
               Opacity="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.125*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.125*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="amountLabel" Text="" TextDecorations="Underline" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="45"/>
                   
            <Label Text="Category" TextDecorations="Underline" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="45" />

            <Button x:Name="scrollLeftButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="R" FontSize="10" Clicked="ScrollLeftButton_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="scrollRightButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="L" FontSize="10" Clicked="ScrollRightButton_Clicked"/>

            <Button x:Name="button1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="1" Clicked="Button1_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="2" Clicked="Button2_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="3" Clicked="Button3_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="4" Clicked="Button4_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="5" Clicked="Button5_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button6" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="6" Clicked="Button6_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button7" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="7" Clicked="Button7_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button8" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="8" Clicked="Button8_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button9" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="9" Clicked="Button9_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="dotButton" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="." Clicked="DotButton_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="button0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="0" Clicked="Button0_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="(--" Clicked="DeleteButton_Clicked"/>

            <Button x:Name="commentButton" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="Comment" FontSize="8" Clicked="CommentButton_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="saveButton" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="Save" FontSize="10"
                    Clicked="SaveButton_Clicked"    />
            <Button x:Name="clearAllButton" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Text="Clear all" FontSize="9" Clicked="ClearAllButton_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
        
        <Frame x:Name="commentFrame"
               BorderColor="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
               CornerRadius="10" Opacity="1"
               
               IsVisible="False">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.85*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Editor x:Name="commentEditorField" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Text" TextColor="Black"/>
                <Button x:Name="commentSaveButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Сохранить" FontSize="11" Clicked="CommentSaveButton_Clicked"/>
                <Button x:Name="commentCancelButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Отменить" FontSize="11" Clicked="CommentCancelButton_Clicked"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>


    </Grid>
        
</ContentPage>
```

Here how it looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTQkT.png)

My AppShell.xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Money_Manager.Views"
       Title="Money_Manager"
       x:Class="Money_Manager.AppShell"
       x:Name="myShell">

    <!--
        The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.
    
        https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
    -->

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>

    <TabBar x:Name="tabBar">
        <ShellContent x:Name="expencesTab" Title="Расход" Icon="icon_expence.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OperationPage}"
                      
                      Shell.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Expence}" Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Expence}"/>
        <ShellContent x:Name="incomeTab" Title="Доход" Icon="icon_income.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OperationPage}"
                      Shell.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Income}" Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Income}"/>
        <ShellContent x:Name="statisticsTab" Title="Статистика" Icon="icon_statistics.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:StatisticsPage}" />
        <ShellContent x:Name="historyTab" Title="История" Icon="icon_history.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HistoryPage}" />
    </TabBar>


</Shell>
```

Thank you all for your comments and suggestions

I tried to find some stuff about this problem in documentation but didn't find articles about sending some data from one page to another or any suitable solution

Comment: checking which tab is active in order to figure out if something is an income or expense seems like a bad design.  Why not pass a flag as a parameter to the page/VM when you navigate to it that determines what kind of operation it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BindableProperty` to achieve this. You can try to add a bindable property in your Content page(`OperationPage.xaml.cs`) and pass a data to page `OperationPage`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class OperationPage : ContentPage
{
    public OperationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Get the value here( `Expences` or `InCome`)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------> arg is : " + Arg);

        this.Title = Arg.ToString();
    }

    //add property Arg
    public string Arg
    {
        set { SetValue(ArgProperty, value); }
        get { return (string)GetValue(ArgProperty); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ArgProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Arg), typeof(string), typeof(OperationPage), string.Empty);

}
```

Then in `AppShell.xaml`, you can pass some special value to the `OperationPage`,just as follows:

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent x:Name="expencesTab" Title="Expences" Icon="image1.png"     >
        <local:OperationPage Arg="Expences">

        </local:OperationPage>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent x:Name="incomeTab" Title="InCome" Icon="image2.png"    >
        <local:OperationPage Arg="InCome">

        </local:OperationPage>
    </ShellContent>

    <!--   other code   --> 
</TabBar>
```

Comment: Hi @VladMask, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.